# can you share detailed product roadmap features are planned for the new GUI Builder past version 3.6.2?

Tags: codenameone

I am an NetBeans 8.2 user that develops forms graphically.
I have been following the examples of the new GUI Builder as a "ground up" development and appreciate your efforts.
I am wondering if and when you will support Free Hand or Absolute layout managers to provide a simpler way to layout screens.

PS: I have the CodenameOne 3.6.2 plugin for NetBeans.
I understand you are releasing 3.7 June 20 and 3,8 in Nov sometime, however no details regarding the new GUI Builder.

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: Did you mean to ask this at the CodenameOne site?  https://www.codenameone.com/about.html

Answer (score 1):

We don't publish the set of upcoming features for a release, I wrote about this before but I can't seem to find the reference.

Historically we announced upcoming features like Windows Phone support and then we constantly pushed them back (because Windows Phone was a pain to support). This created a situation where no one was happy, the people waiting for the Windows Phone release were disappointed since we rushed to market something that was "half baked" and the majority of our developers who had other priorities weren't happy either.

As a result of that we decided to only define dates for the releases and release "what's ready". We sometimes discuss the things we are working on but release dates are agile. So we are working on on-device-debugging & a new update to the GUI builder that has better layout support. The on-device-debugging feature won't make it to 3.7 I hope it will make it to the next release but can't guarantee (note you can debug on device with the native IDE's today but it's a pain in comparison).

We want the new GUI builder work to be sublime, if it's not we'd rather push it back than release a half baked product. Currently it's still on the 3.7 feature list which is rapidly narrowing and we consider it to be an important feature which is pretty much the most I can say about this.

Comment: Thanks, I completely understand, I look forward to the new release with GUI Builder.